# Can't show Stream video from vlcj

Tags: java, streaming, vlc, vlcj

I run this sample code from [vlcj sample page](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/streaming/StreamHttp.java). I enter `http://127.0.0.1:5555` in browser and **VLC player**, but don't show any things.

```
public class StreamHttp extends VlcjTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Specify a single MRL to stream");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String media = args[0];
    String options = formatHttpStream("127.0.0.1", 5555);

    System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options);

    // Don't exit
    Thread.currentThread().join();
}

private static String formatHttpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
    sb.append(":sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,");
    sb.append("dst=");
    sb.append(serverAddress);
    sb.append(':');
    sb.append(serverPort);
    sb.append("}}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try pointing to a streaming service?

Comment: Did you talk about code or question?

Answer (score 0):

- use `options=
  ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=56,venc=x264{profile=baseline},fps=12,width=176,height=144,acodec=mp3,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/"`
  you can look for more options string in VLC->stream feature
- Pass a valid mrl.